# Regex search for a 4 digit number without a comma and replace with comma

Tags: regex

Im working on trying to add commas after a 4 digit group so I can import it into a spreadsheet and create a HTML table out of it. If anyone has a better idea let me know.
Basically, I have this text:

```
1860s this is some text.
1911, what the hell is this
1916, maybe something else
1921, keeping it going
1925 working it
1930 what the hell.
```

Im trying to figure out the best way to add text into a HTML table and using the comma as the seperator. I thought regex would be good to add commas after each 4 digit number. Then I could import it into a spread sheet and export it out as a html table.

I got the input express right I think, but i cant seem to replace the line leaving the 4 digit number while adding a comma to each line without one.

Here is my search expression:

```
[0-9]{4}[^\,^\-^\.]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To add commas to the four digit number which isn't followed by `,`

```
\b(\d{4})(?![\d,])
```

To add commas to the four digit number which isn't followed by `,`, `-`, `.`

```
\b(\d{4})(?![\d,.-])
```

Then replace the matched strings with `\1,` or `$1,`, it's based on your language or tool you're running.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gP1eN6/1)